# Pandas find columns with wildcard names

Tags: pandas

I  have a pandas dataframe  with column names like this:

```
id ColNameOrig_x ColNameOrig_y
```

There are many such columns, the 'x' and 'y' came about because 2 datasets with similar column names were merged.
What I need to do:

```
df.ColName = df.ColNameOrig_x + df.ColNameOrig_y
```

I am now manually repeating this line for many cols(close to 50), is there a wildcard way of doing this?

Comment: So you joined two data tables together that had the exact same column names. Instead of a join, could you do a union on those two data sets? If the data sets allow for a union, then it might be the better option since then you wouldn't have duplicate column names like that. Once you union'd the two tables together, you could simply sum the values in each column since each column will appear only once. Whether or not this is feasible depends on the nature of your data sets, but the type of problem you're running into makes me think that a union might be possible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the subscripting syntax to access column names dynamically:

```
col_groups = ['ColName1', 'ColName2']
for grp in col_groups:
    df[grp] = df[f'{grp}Orig_x'] + df[f'{grp}Orig_y']
```

---

Or you can aggregate by column group. For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8]
], columns=['ColName1Orig_x', 'ColName1Orig_y', 'ColName2Orig_x', 'ColName2Orig_y'])

# Here's your opportunity to define the wildcard
col_groups = df.columns.str.extract('(.+)Orig_[x|y]')[0]

df.columns = [col_groups, df.columns]
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```

Input:

```
ColName1Orig_x  ColName1Orig_y  ColName2Orig_x  ColName2Orig_y
             1               2               3               4
             5               6               7               8
```

Output:

```
ColName1  ColName2
       3         7
      11        15
```

Comment: Thank tyou. What does the f' mean : df[f'{?

Comment: See Python f-strings https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by lambda function and `axis=1` for grouping per columns names with aggregate `sum` or use text functions like [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with indexing:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='_').groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).sum()
print (df1)
   ColName1Orig  ColName2Orig
0             3             7
1            11            15

df1 = df.filter(like='_').groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1).sum()
print (df1)
   ColName1Orig  ColName2Orig
0             3             7
1            11            15

df1 = df.filter(like='_').groupby(df.columns.str[:12], axis=1).sum()
print (df1)
   ColName1Orig  ColName2Orig
0             3             7
1            11            15
```